# app database generated file having errors in moor flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-moor

I am using moor package in flutter for my application. im following the instructions online
https://moor.simonbinder.eu/docs/getting-started/starting_with_sql/#what-moor-generates

but when i run the build command:  flutter pub run build_runner build
the appdatabase.g.dart file that gets generated has errors. here is a snapshot of errors:

[image]

[image]

here is my dependencies

```
cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  month_picker_dialog: ^0.3.1
  flutter_cupertino_localizations: ^1.0.1
  moor: ^2.3.0
  provider: ^4.0.3
  moor_ffi: ^0.4.0
  path_provider: ^1.6.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  intl_translation: ^0.17.1
  moor_generator: ^2.3.1
  build_runner:
```

the problem seems to be with 'Table' class. there is a conflict between dart and moor. the message indicate there are two versions.  how can i solve this problem so that my error goes away

Answer (score 0):

the answer is to use  import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart' hide Table;

Answer (score 0):

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  #moor database

   moor_flutter: ^3.1.0

  # For the UI
  provider: ^4.3.1

  # For OS-specific directory paths
  path_provider: ^1.6.11
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

   #new Dependencies  add

   moor_generator: ^3.2.0
 
   build_runner:
```

> Step 1 : delete file appdatabase.g.dart

> step 2: flutter clean

> Step 3: flutter pub get

> Step 4: flutter pub run build_runner build watch

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you don't have the 'import' of your table or dao in your AppDb class, in my case I have more than 90 tables and dao's, I separated then in a class with a static list, but I need do the imports of my files in the app_database.dart too, because of the error.

I have this class for tables:

```
import '../tables/table_one.dart';
import '../tables/table_two.dart';

class TableList {  
  static const List<Type> tables = [
    TableOne,
    TableTwo,
  ]
}
```

And another for Dao files:

```
import '../dao/table_one_dao.dart';
import '../dao/table_two_dao.dart';

class DaoList{  
  static const List<Type> daos= [
    TableOne,
    TableTwo,
  ]
}
```

And this is my AppDb class:

```
import '../tables/table_one.dart';
import '../tables/table_two.dart';
import '../dao/table_one_dao.dart';
import '../dao/table_two_dao.dart';
part 'app_db.g.dart';

@DriftDatabase(
  tables: TableList.tables,
  daos: DaoList.daos,
)
class AppDb extends _$AppDb {
  AppDb() : super(_openConnection());

  @override
  int get schemaVersion => 1;
}

LazyDatabase _openConnection() {
  return LazyDatabase(() async {
    final dbFolder = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final file = File(p.join(dbFolder.path, 'app_database.db'));
    return NativeDatabase(file);
  });
}
```

As you see, i have to declare the imports again in my AppDb file to resolve. If you declare your tables directly in the AppDb escope, i think you don't have problem.